# Burninate [application-scoped] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[application-scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-scoped) has had 2 questions in 2 months, has no tag wiki, and no synonyms.

[One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281314/can-we-share-cdi-applicationscoped-bean-instance-accross-web-application-in-the) deals with a particular annotation in Java, and I am unable to figure out why this tag was used at all in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547806/expire-all-sessions-on-tomcat-application-restart-programmatically).

Given the inconsistency in the only two questions, the tag does not have a clear purpose

I recommend burninating the tag, as it does not appear to refer to anything meaningful.

**UPDATE**

This tag has been burninated. No further action required.

Comment: Sometimes, one can simply do it. Like in this case.

Comment: @Deduplicator OK. edited the tags out of the posts, but have to wait for the edits to be approved.

Comment: Done. Tag count: 0.